# How to count and rename duplicate rows in a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates, datarow

I found plenty of stuff on deleting duplicates, but I couldn't find any guidance for the problem below anywhere...

I'm looking for a way to rename any duplicate rows in a C# DataTable that I've imported to from a CSV. My data looks something like:

```
**Name**       **Item**                 **Quantity**
ABC            Item_Name                     6
ABC            Item_Name_2                   1
DEF            Item_Name                     3
GHI            Item_Name_2                   7
ABC            Item_Name                     6
ABC            Item_Name                     1
JKL            Item_Name_3                   4
ABC            Item_Name                     6
ABC            Item_Name                     1
JKL            Item_Name_3                   4
```

What I would like the data to look like, if a whole row (quantity included) appears more than once, is this:

```
**Name**          **Item**                 **Quantity**
ABC            Item_Name                        6
ABC            Item_Name_2                      1
DEF            Item_Name                        3
GHI            Item_Name_2                      7
ABC (2)        Item_Name                        6
ABC (2)        Item_Name_2                      1
JKL            Item_Name_3                      4
ABC (3)        Item_Name                        6
ABC (3)        Item_Name_2                      1
JKL (2)        Item_Name_3                      4
```

At present, I'm using a double "for loop" to determine which rows further down the table have the same data as the present row and rename them accordingly. Clearly, this has two issues:

1. It's really slow with tables with a large number of rows, obviously
2. All future rows whose name column was "ABC" now have a name column "ABC (2)", regardless of whether this is their first second or 98th occurrence (because, to be frank, my code sucks).

Any help anyone can offer greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach(DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
    {
        string name = row.Item[0].ToString();

        if(name[name.Length - 3] == '(' && name[name.Length - 1] == ')')
            continue;

        string item = row.Item[1].ToString();
        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row.Item[2]);
        string expression = "Name = " + name + " and Item = " + item + " and Quantity = " + quantity;

        DataRow[] matchingRows = table.Select(expression);
        for(int i = 1; i < matchingRows.Length; i++)
            matchingRows[i]["Name"] += " (" + i + ")";  
    }
```

Basically, I just looped through each row.  Then, I query every row that is identical.  Then, I loop through those identical rows, and rename them with an appended string of (1), (2), (3), etc. (in the order the query found them).  I also skip any rows I've already renamed with that 'if' statement (I assume a renamed row ends with "(" at the 3rd to last char and ")" at its last char).  Sorry if I made C#-syntax-related errors in the code.  The idea is pretty straightforward, though.

Comment: It's doing everything right except committing the changes to the DataTable. I can't import or load the rows into the Table, because it conflicts with the "in" enumeration in the "foreach". Any tips?

Comment: hmm. try matchingRows[i]["Name"] += " (" + i + ")" OR matchingRows[i].SetField("Name", matchingRows[i]["Name"] + " (" + i + ")"). if that doesn't work, try setting thisTable.Columns.readOnly = false.

Comment: Yep... using matchingRows[i]["Name"] sorted it out. Is there a logical explanation why making the change to the named column works and making the change to the ItemArray doesn't? 

This is the first question I've asked on here, shall I edit your answer to include that change and then mark it as a solution? Is that usually how this works?

Comment: the item array is just a COPY of the contents of that row, not actual references. so you arent actually modifying the true row. ill edit the answer, then you can just mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different solution. In my opinion, more elegant!

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));

        // Data for test
        table.Rows.Add("ABC", "Item_name", 6);
        table.Rows.Add("ABC", "Item_name", 6);
        table.Rows.Add("ABC2", "Item_name", 6);
        table.Rows.Add("ABC2", "Item_name", 6);
        table.Rows.Add("ABC2", "Item_name", 6);
        table.Rows.Add("ABC2", "Item_name", 6);

        // Query with Linq
        var query = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by new {
                        name  = row.Field<String>("Name"),
                        title = row.Field<String>("Title")
                    } into GrpNameTitle
                    select new {
                        Name  = GrpNameTitle.Key.name + " (" + GrpNameTitle.Count() + ")", 
                        Title = GrpNameTitle.Key.title,
                        Quantity = GrpNameTitle.First().Field<int>("Quantity")
                    };


        foreach (var itm in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", itm.Name, itm.Title);
        }
```

I have a question, when you filter your rows "group by" on your two columns (name and title) would it not make sense to add/calculate the third column contains the quantity ? For example:

```
abc item_name 2
abc item_name 2
```

give this result:

```
abc(2) item_name 4
```

Best regards,

Mentor Reka.

Comment: Nice idea, but no, that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I probably should have been clearer about my end goal. I just want to mark these datarows as legitimate duplicates, as the source CSV forms part of something from which the end user can place an order, so I just want to mark these rows as separate instances of the same type of order to show they've not been entered in error.